# Browser is not able to download .apk file instead it downloads .txt

Tags: android, apk

I have created apk download website to my user. I have hosted all android apps in `.apk` format. In that, while user accessing the file using `.apk` formal from chrome browser it is working fine. In Case, if they access from MI browser, it is not downloading, instead of that, the browser downloads `.txt` files.

Comment: What is the Content-Type the server is providing in the response headers?